# Evaluate $\sum{\left(\frac{1}{1+a_n}\right)}$ where $a_n=(-1)^{n+1}\sum{\left(\binom{2n+1}{2k}2^k\right)}$

Tags: summation

Suppose $\left\{a_n\right\}$ is a sequence defined by:

$$a_n:=\left(-1\right)^{n+1} \sum_{k=0}^n {\left(\binom{2n+1}{2k}2^k\right)}$$

The problem is to evaluate:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {\left(\frac{1}{1+a_n}\right)}$$

An estimate for the value of the sum is approximately $0.1036$.

One curious thing I was able to find is that the denominator of the sum can be factored:

$$\left(1+a_n\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(-1\right)^{n+1}\left({\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)}^n-{\left(1-\sqrt{2}\right)}^n\right)\left({\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)}^{n+1}-{\left(1-\sqrt{2}\right)}^{n+1}\right)$$

But I do not know how to use this factorization to solve the sum.

Any ideas?? Thanks!